# How to set condition in for loop to break

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, statistics, regression

I try to adjust the AR(1) ols small sample bias,so I write a code then set break in the loop function but always failed，how could I set the condition in for loop ?

```
n = 31 # simulate regression samples

yt <- c()

ANS <- rep(NA,1000) # create a place for beta loop

for (M in c((1:3)/100)) { # after 1000 beta loop, I want simulate AR(1)+0.01 (EX:0.91、0.92、0.93...) Data for next loop in beta
  
  for (i in 1:1000){ # Monte Carole to estimate beta

yt[1] <- rnorm(1,0,1)

  for (z in 2:n) { # simulate AR(1)=0.9+M loop 
  
  yt[z] <- (0.9 + M) * yt[z-1] + rnorm(1,0,1)
  
}

yt

X <- yt[-n]

beta <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% yt[-1] # Estimate AR(1) coeff(beta)

ANS[i] <- sort(beta) 

cat(M," ","\n")

### if (beta[500] - 0.9 <= 0.01) break ### I want set this condition to stop loop but failed , get error message : Error in if (beta[500] - 0.9 <= 1) break , missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
}}

ifelse(abs(quantile(ANS , probs = c(0.5)) - 0.9) <= 0.01, TRUE, FALSE ) # Because I didn't know how to set break in it, I had to operate it manually
```

.

Below I try to add "if (beta[500] - 0.9 <= 0.01) break" condition to stop loop (Failed)

```
n = 31 # simulate regression samples

yt <- c()

ANS <- rep(NA,1000) # create a place for beta loop

for (M in c((1:3)/100)) { # after 1000 beta loop, I want simulate AR(1)+0.01 (EX:0.91、0.92、0.93...) Data for next loop in beta
  
  for (i in 1:1000){ # Monte Carole to estimate beta

yt[1] <- rnorm(1,0,1)

  for (z in 2:n) { # simulate AR(1)=0.9+M loop 
  
  yt[z] <- (0.9 + M) * yt[z-1] + rnorm(1,0,1)
  
}

yt

X <- yt[-n]

beta <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% yt[-1] # Estimate AR(1) coeff(beta)

ANS[i] <- sort(beta) 

cat(M," ","\n")

if (beta[500] - 0.9 <= 0.01) break 
}}
```

Does anyone Know why I get error when i am set the condition ? # if (beta[500] - 0.9 <= 0.01) break #
Very thanks!!

Comment: Might be useful to post your error

Comment: Don't use `ifelse` here. If your conditional is known to be of length 1, then you should use `if` and optionally `else`. Period. There are a few gotchas with using `ifelse`, and as in this case mis-use of it indicates poor design.

Comment: Further, your check on the quantile is *outside* of the `for` loop, so `break` won't work. If you want to interrupt a `for` loop, you need `if` and you need to put in *inside* the `for` loop, such as `for (ing in 1:100) { if (ind > 50) break ; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` is going to break out of the closest `for` loop, but not anything outside of it. In this case, it's within the inner loop, `for (1 in 1:1000)`, so it'll break out of that but the outer loop (`for (M in ...)`) will continue.

If you want the condition inside the inner loop but want it to break out of both, consider a flag of some sort that is predefined to not break out, but set when you need it. I'll use `breakout` here:

```r
breakout <- FALSE
n = 31 # simulate regression samples
yt <- c()
ANS <- rep(NA,1000) # create a place for beta loop
for (M in c((1:3)/100)) {
  for (i in 1:1000){
    yt[1] <- rnorm(1,0,1)
    for (z in 2:n) {
      yt[z] <- (0.9 + M) * yt[z-1] + rnorm(1,0,1)
    }
    yt
    X <- yt[-n]
    beta <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% yt[-1] # Estimate AR(1) coeff(beta)
    ANS[i] <- sort(beta) 
    cat(M," ","\n")
    if (beta[500] - 0.9 <= 0.01) {
      breakout <- TRUE
      break
    }
  }
  if (breakout) break
}
```

You haven't shared your error, so I'll show:

```
Error in if (beta[500] - 0.9 <= 0.01) break (from #12) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Why is this? You are referencing `beta[500]` when `beta` is only a single number. You should be tracing through your code manually to find where an error occurs, as this is the fastest way to narrow down the error.

```r
M <- 0.01
i <- 1
    yt[1] <- rnorm(1,0,1)
    for (z in 2:n) { # simulate AR(1)=0.9+M loop 
      yt[z] <- (0.9 + M) * yt[z-1] + rnorm(1,0,1)
    }
    X <- yt[-n]
    beta <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% yt[-1] # Estimate AR(1) coeff(beta)
beta
#          [,1]
# [1,] 0.890663
    ANS[i] <- sort(beta) 
    cat(M," ","\n")
# 0.01   
    if (beta[500] - 0.9 <= 0.01) break 
# Error in if (beta[500] - 0.9 <= 0.01) break : 
#   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
#     x
```

So why is this?

```r
beta[500] - 0.9 <= 0.01
# [1] NA
beta[500]
# [1] NA
beta
#          [,1]
# [1,] 0.890663
```

So why is this? Well, even when `i` is 1000, `beta` is a matrix reduction to a 1x1 matrix. The premise of your conditional `beta[500]` is broken. I don't know what you think it should be compared to, but that isn't going to work.

Fix the logic behind your math, and then run through the code step-by-step to make sure the dimensions/lengths and such are what you imagined they are.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, especially the explanation about the "break" function. I learned a lesson from it. And the purpose of I want to set "break" is to stop the "for M loop" . If the median is very close to the original coefficient of 0.9 then stop.

Comment: I have run your code, but still get same error. Not sure which step is wrong. Or using while to loop is beter then for in conditions?

Comment: You need to learn how to troubleshoot your code. I stepped through it for you, demonstrating where the error I see resides and why it's an error. I don't know how to fix it because I don't know what you think you're trying to do. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help! From your message I realize why I got an error. I use na.omit function to remove NAs and change the median to mean. It's work.